# Another word for "manufactured" with regards to argumentative statements

Tags: single-word-requests

which on the surface look genuine and possibly discovered but are in fact architected in some way to support a pre-existing position. there is the element of deception, intentional or otherwise

I'm specifically looking for that word which ends in "-ed"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The argument would be said to be [*contrived*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+contrive).

Deliberately and artificially created.

Answer (score 9):

***"Concocted"*** gives the impression of having been manufactured to deceive, as in the 2nd definition of ["concoct"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concoct) from MW-O:

> "to invent or develop (a plan, story, etc.) especially in order to trick or deceive someone"

Answer (score 5):

I'd propose **"fabricated"**. Similar to Kristina's "concoct", ["fabricate"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fabricate) is defined by M-W as:

> to create or make up (something, such as a story) in order to trick people

Answer (score 0):

Kind of colloquial, "bullied out of his [butt]"